# Ubuntu 22.04 - snap based firefox won't start using remote profile

Tags: firefox, snap, user-profile

I hope I didn't miss a relevant question/answer. I have installed firefox on ubuntu 22.04 as snap. My profile is stored on an usb drive. Firefox is allowed to access removable media, I can access the drive and also save pages there from within firefox. Now when I move the firefox profile (the firefox dir with all subdirs) to the usb drive and link it via symlink, firefox won't start.
Is this unavoidable or what needs to be done to make this work like in deb based installs?
Thanks a million for your support!

Comment: A [somewhat similar question](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/firefox-snap-no-longer-reads-usr-lib-firefox-for-customization/29713) led to a [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1786742), and Mozilla developer discussion that basically ended with "*don't use the Snap for that*." In theory, you might be able to use [Firefox Autoconfig](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-autoconfig), but there's a bit of a learning curve there, and the same bug report discussion seemed doubtful about it.

Comment: Thanks! This helps.

Comment: removed the snap, installed the tarball, created a .desktop-file. Works!